# Does Bash have version issues that would prevent me from executing files?

Tags: bash

I've created a bash shell script file that I can run on my local bash (version 4.2.10) but not on a remote computer (version 3.2).  Here's what I'm doing

- A script file (some_script.sh) exists in a local folder
- I've done `$ chmod 755 some_script.sh` to make it an executable
- Now, I try `$ ./some_script.sh`

On my computer, this runs fine.  On the remote computer, this returns a Command not found error:
`./some_script.sh: Command not found.`

Also, in the remote version, executable files have stars(*) following their names.  Don't know if this makes any difference but I still get the same error when I include the star.

Is this because of the bash shell version?  Any ideas to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Check your ["shebang"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line at the top of the script. Is the location of `bash` indicated there the same as on the other system?

Comment: Sanity check, is that script on the remote file system that you are attempting to run it on?

Comment: That shouldn't matter for this error.  Since it doesn't even read the file.  However, I did put the bash reference in the wrong place...

Comment: I'm confused at how you have arrived at 'Command not found" error", but if you say that there are asterisks appended to file names on the remote system (marking an executable file in some shells), I assume you see the script you are trying to run on the remote machine. Can you also double check that the script has +x mode on the remote system, and that the script is in the default home directory of the user which you are ssh'ing as

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `command not found` message can be a bit misleading.  The "command" in question can be either the script you're trying to execute *or* the shell specified on the shebang line.

For example, on my system:

```
% cat foo.sh
#!/no/such/dir/sh

echo hello
% ./foo.sh
./foo.sh: Command not found.
```

`./foo.sh` clearly exists; it's the interpreter `/no/such/dir/sh` that doesn't exist.  (I find that the error message varies depending on the shell from which you invoke `foo.sh`.)

So the problem is almost certainly that you've specified an incorrect interpreter name on line one of `some_script.sh`.  Perhaps `bash` is installed in a different location (it's usually `/bin/bash`, but not always.)

As for the `*` characters in the names of executable files, those aren't actually part of the file names.  The `-F` option to the `ls` command causes it to show a special character after certain kinds of files: `*` for executables, `/` for directories, `@` for symlinks, and so forth.   Probably on the remote system you have `ls` aliased to `ls -F` or something similar.  If you type `/bin/ls`, bypassing the alias, you should see the file names without the append `*` characters; if you type `/bin/ls -F`, you should see the `*`s again.

Adding a `*` character in a command name doesn't do what you think it's doing, but it *probably* won't make any difference.  For example, if you type

```
./some_script.sh*
```

the `*` is a wild card, and the command name expands to a list of all files in the current directory whose names match the pattern (this is completely different from the meaning of `*` as an executable file in `ls -F` output).  Chances are there's only one such file, so
`./some_script.sh*` is probably equivalent to `./some_script.sh`.  But don't type the `*`; it's unnecessary and can cause unexpected results.

Comment: Also make sure you use the correct line endings for your platform. dos2unix is a helpful tool.

Comment: Thanks Keith.  I'm glad you've taught me all this stuff.  It was very informative!